# Three way join with aggregation using HIVE and HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

This is essentially a design question that I have. Looking for the most efficient way to perform this. Here is the scenario....

We have three pieces of data. They are:

```
DATASET 1 (HDFS) (Primary key: acct_num)
acct_num
3111
6111

DATASET 2 (HIVE) (Primary key: acct_num & cust_num)
acct_num|cust_num
1111|AAAA
2111|AAAA
3111|BBBB
4111|CCCC
5111|DDDD
6111|DDDD

DATASET 3 (HIVE) (Primary key: acct_num)
acct_num|last_cycle_dt
1111|20181225
2111|20190118
3111|20181220
4111|20181227
5111|20181223
6111|20181222
```

What I'm trying to do is create an HDFS file from a dataframe that is a selection of accounts who satisfy the below criteria:

Accounts that either exist in DATASET 1 OR accounts who's last cycle date (last_cycle_dt) is GREATER than a provided date value. Here's the curveball: if you satisfy the above OR statement, we ALSO want to bring in all of your relationship accounts (so if customer AAAA satisfies the above condition for any of his accounts we will bring in ALL of his accounts).

So let's say the "provided date value" is 20180116. Based on the rules I stated above we would need to bring in ALL the accounts that exist in DATASET1 (because if you're in DATASET 1 you always need to be in) and any accounts who's last cycle date (last_cycle_dt) is GREATER than 20180116. The only accounts who satisfy that are accounts 2111 and 5111. BUT, we now need to bring in the relationship accounts to that customer (FOR BOTH THE ACCOUNTS IN DATASET 1 AND IF YOU SATISFIED THE LAST CYCLE DATE LOGIC!!!). So our final dataset would be (which would include columns from all the datasets that we joined)

```
RESULTS DATAFRAME (Written to HDFS)
acct_num|cust_num|last_cycle_dt
1111|AAAA|20170125
2111|AAAA|20180118
3111|BBBB|20171220
5111|DDDD|20181223
6111|DDDD|20181222
```

1111 and 2111 were brought in because 2111 satisfied the last cycle date logic and so we brought in the relationship. 3111 was brought in because it existed in DATASET 1. 5111 and 6111 were brought in because 6111 existed in DATASET 1 and we brought in the relationship.

I'll be coding this in JAVA using SPARK. I'm looking for a high level design of performing this in the most efficient way possible. Example code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Ideallg you should try something yourself first. I would also advise using Scala over Java.

Comment: My first thought is to join Dataset 1 and Dataset 3 under the conditions IF your last cycle date is GREATER than the given date OR you're account numbers are equal between the two. Store that in a dataframe. THen from there we can go back to Dataset 2 to get the relationship accounts. That would be a 2 step process.

Comment: There are new features like statistics, not tried though.  May be an idea to indicate dataset sizes.